# Databinding 2 WPF ComboBoxes to 1 source without being "linked"

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml

I have a master-detail scenario where I have 1 ComboBox listing companies from an ObjectDataSourceProvider.  Under that I have 2 ComboBoxes binding to the Contacts property from the current Company object.  I need to be able to select a different contact in each ComboBox; however, as soon as I change selection in one list the other list updates to the same contact.

I have tried different settings (OneWay vs. TwoWay) but so far nothing seems to work.  Here is an excerpt of my XAML.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <!-- This is a custom class inheriting from ObjectDataProvider -->
    <wg:CustomersDataProvider x:Key="CompanyDataList" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <!--- other layout XAML removed -->
    <ComboBox x:Name="Customer" Width="150"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CompanyDataList},Path=Companies,Mode=OneWay}"
              DisplayMemberPath="Name"
              SelectedValuePath="Id"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Id, Mode=OneWay}" 
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />

    <ComboBox x:Name="PrimaryContact" Width="150"
              DataContext="{Binding ElementName=Customer,Path=Items,Mode=OneWay}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Contacts,Mode=OneWay}"
              DisplayMemberPath="FullName"
              SelectedValuePath="Id"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Id,Mode=OneWay}" />

    <ComboBox x:Name="AdminContact" Width="150"
              DataContext="{Binding ElementName=OwnerCustomer,Path=Items,Mode=OneWay}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Contacts,Mode=OneWay}"
              DisplayMemberPath="FullName"
              SelectedValuePath="Id"
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Id,Mode=OneWay}" />

    <!--- other layout XAML removed -->
</Grid>
```

I thought that creating a CollectionViewSource would be the way to go, but I have not been able to make that work.  Is there a simple way to do this so the PrimaryContact and AdminContact aren't linked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your "[IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem.aspx)" attributes to "False".

Comment: Brilliant, although that has caused another issue, I think I can work with it.  Thanks Bob, you seem to be quite a WPF guru!

Comment: I think WPF is so big, no one, except for maybe Petzold, will be a guru :-)